# Logback is not creating a new log file after reaching to its maxsize

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I want the working configuration for logback xml, when my logback creates xml and once  it reaches the maxsize of the file, then it should create a new log file instead of overriding the old log, and the old file should be zipped. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks, here is what I have tried ...

```
contextName>ETL-SERVICE</contextName>
<appender name="RootFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${catalina.base}/logs/etl-service.log</file>
<append>true</append>

<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>etl-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you need to include the full path in .  The files are probably being created somewhere unexpected, or not being created since the process doesn't have permission to create files in its working directory.